# c# how to sort 2D array values

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, 2d

I have 2 arrays

```
string[,] marksMatrix = new string[5, 4];
string[] studentIDArr = new string[5];
```

Marks matrix has the marks of 5 students for 4 subjects and their student IDs are stored in the studentIDArr. When I display the student IDs and marks of each student, how do I sort it in ascending order of the student IDs?

```
textBox2.Text = "StudentID\tOOAD\tDWA\tDB\tWAD\r\n";
int rowlength = marksMatrix.GetLength(0);
int collength = marksMatrix.GetLength(1);

for (int y = 0; y < rowlength; y++) {
  textBox2.Text += studentIDArr[y];
  for (int x = 0; x < collength; x++) {
    textBox2.Text += "\t" + marksMatrix[y,x];
  }
  textBox2.Text += "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: So you actually want to sort studentIDArr which is 1D?

Comment: Yup! I know how to sort that but i don't know how to sort the marks matrix such that that marks that belongs to the student is also correctly reflected when i display the student IDs and marks

Comment: check my logic explanation. If you need help with the code implementation or you have questions let me know.

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't have `class Student{string Name, List<int> Marks;}` instead of storing this information in 2 arrays?

Comment: Are your values really strings?  For instance, is a `StudentId` a number or a string?  That would impact how to sort it. Sorting numerically vs. alphabetically are 2 very different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is:

1. Declare a new vector of strings (let's call it studentIDArrSorted)
2. Sort studentIDArr and store it in studentIDArrSorted, without altering the order of studentIDArr.
3. Now take a for on studentIDArrSorted
4. For studentIDArrSorted[i], search is position in studentIDArr.
5. Print the corresponding column from marksMatrix.

Example:
Initial list : "3", "4", "2"
Sorted list: "2", "3", "4"

The old position of "2" in list was 3, so you must print the 3th line from the matrix.
Note: I assume that the ids are unique.

A more simple solution will be to store the both arrays (the marks and the ids) in an object. This will get rid of all the overhead.